# A Sql server reporting service error

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm facing a strange problem..
I've developed few reports. they are working fine in develop environment. after successfull testing they were published on web.
in web version, all reports are executing for first time.. if I change any of parameters values or without chaning also..
if I press "View Report"  following error occurs..

```
"An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
    Query execution failed for data set 'dsMLGDB2Odbc'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
        For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors"
```

please suggest any alternative ways to overcome this issue
thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, log into the server that is running SSRS and IIS then try running the report.  This should give you more information about the error message.  You can also check the log directory on the SSRS server to see if there is anything about the error in there.  Post any of this information to help us solve the problem.